# Compile error when using FFMPEG library

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ffmpeg

I have tried to compile a C program using FFMPEG but every time I compile it fails at the include statement:

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
```

Gcc provides this error message:

```
libavcodec/avcodec.h: No such file or directory
```

I have installed FFMPEG and created the shared libraries, but when I try to link those libraries when I compile I get the same error.

```
gcc main.c -L ffmpeg_build/lib -l ffmpeg_build/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h
```

Do I get this error because I am linking the library incorrectly, or is there some other issue?

This is the first time I am using someone else's library, so please excuse me if I am asking a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lowercase `-l` is a linker option used to specify *libraries*. They might look like `libsomething.a` and becomes `-lsomething` in the linker invocation. In order to add a directory to the header search path, use a capital i, `-I`.

```
gcc main.c -L/some/path/ffmpeg_build/lib -I/some/path/ffmpeg_build/include
```